# what is the right formula to calculate the crossing point of 2 lines, while having only the points associated to the lines?

Tags: excel

what is the formula for calculating the crossing point of 2 lines when the input is the coordination of the lines - using excel formula for X and Y.

i can calculate each line function - but how to compare the two functions to calculate the crossing point ?

[image: this is how the excel looks like:]

Comment: Since, by looking at your diagram,  the starting point of each line is arbitrary, it's going to be a challenge. Also, What if you increase/decrease, rowheights/collumnwidhts? This will influence the crossing point too. A mathematical formula would not account for excel cells but actual coordinates I think. So I doubt a formula is your go to here, or the other way around; if you have coordinates, excel cells is not your go to method.

Comment: thanks! the excel lines are not relevant. lets say A1=2, A2=7, A3=6 & A4=6 -> representing coordination of line 1. and B1=3, B2=2, B3=6, B4=6 -> representing line 2. Now how do i calculate the crossing point ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

***EDIT: Lines defined by points (A1,A2) -> (A3,A4) and (B1,B2) -> (B3,B4)***

Let the lines follow a system of linear equations:

> **y1=m1x1+c1** or **y=(A4-A2)/(A3-A1)*x + A2-(A4-A2)/(A3-A1)*A1**
>
> so m1=(A4-A2)/(A3-A1) and c1=A2-(A4-A2)/(A3-A1)*A1
>
> **y2=m2x2+c2** or **y=(B4-B2)/(B3-B1)*x + B2-(B4-B2)/(B3-B1)*B1**
>
> so m2=(B4-B2)/(B3-B1) and c2=B2-(B4-B2)/(B3-B1)*B1

Where:

- m1: Gradient or Slope of line1
- c1: Intercept of line1
- m2: Gradient or Slope of line2
- c2: Intercept of line2

The intersection point will be (u,v). They must satisfy the above 2 equations.

> **v=m1u+c1**
>
> **v=m2u+c2**

Then m1u+c1=m2u+c2 so:

> **u= (c2-c1)/(m1-m2)**
>
> **v=m1*u+c1**

Use SLOPE and INTERCEPT functions to replicate these equations in Excel:

```
u=(INTERCEPT(y-values2,x-values2)-INTERCEPT(y-values1,x-values1))/(SLOPE(y-values1,x-values1)-SLOPE(y-values2,x-values2))

v =SLOPE(y-values1,x-values1)*X+INTERCEPT(y-values1,x-values1)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer... i need a bit more assistance here. the excel lines are not relevant. lets say A1=2, A2=7, A3=6 & A4=6 -> representing coordination of line 1. and B1=3, B2=2, B3=6, B4=6 -> representing line 2. Now how do i calculate the crossing point ??

Comment: I will edit the post considering the lines (A1,A2)-(A3,A4) and (B1,B2)-(B3,B4)

Comment: I think this is basically the right answer except that u seems to change to s in the middle and back again?

Comment: Sorry, my original formulation use s&t instead of u&v... I forgot some "s". Fixed